# Map a struts2 action result to a controller instead of a jsp

Tags: struts2, struts

I'm working on on a site built using struts2.  The vast majority of our targets generate xml, so mapping the result to a jsp page makes sense.  A couple of our targets actually generated binaries.  I'm wondering if there is a convenient way to say that the result should come from a servlet/controller instead of a jsp.

Obviously this could be done by modifying the web.xml so the struts filter doesn't apply to those targets and mapping those targets as servlets, but this is non-ideal.  Currently, the struts filter applies to the entire site, and we would like to keep it that way.

Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand you scenario, but it seems to me you want the  [Stream Result](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/stream-result.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find an excellent tutorial with code examples about Struts2 file upload and file download that covers the Stream Result:

http://www.jeetrainers.com/struts2-course/chapter12-13-1-1#slide